# Your favorite testing "gem(s)" or "plugins" in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd

Allright people. I'm fond of TDD and testing in general. I personally think it's a good practice when developing.

Since i'm practicing ruby, I never felt the need to try some "testing gems" like rspec for example. I tried Cucumber for high level testing and webrat for integration testing.

**What are the gems you like and why?**

Please give some examples or pointers to web sites explaining the differences.

For example, why should I switch from the basic unit testing FWK rails is giving me to rspec? From webrat to capybara? From Cucumber to steack?

It can be futile things like: *I like this one because the console output is colored* as more important things as: *I like that one because I think it's more expressive when writing ++++ against that: ++++*.

If this question already exists, juste send me the link!

**EDIT**

I changed the title to be more explicit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just an insane amount of testing frameworks available to ruby, choosing one comes down to personal preference really. My personal favorite is [riot](https://github.com/thumblemonks/riot)

Riot makes a few assumptions about how tests should be written. Two big ones are that you should be testing one "thing" per test, and that assertions shouldn't modify that "thing". By making those assumptions, tests can be dramatically sped up, since they only need to run the setup once per block (rather then once for every test).

an example from the readme

```
context "An Array" do
  setup { Array.new }

  context "with one element" do
    setup { topic << "foo" }
    asserts("is not empty") { !topic.empty? }
    asserts("returns the element on #first") { topic.first == "foo" }
  end
end
```

`topic` is the way you refer to what was setup in the `setup`. That is also just the basics of the syntax, there is an idea of "Assertion Macros" which let you DRY up your tests. You could also use `denies` rather then `asserts` for a negative assertion. With those two things in mind, the above example could be written as

```
context "An Array" do
  setup { Array.new }

  context "with one element" do
    setup { topic << "foo" }
    denies("is not empty") { topic }.empty?
    asserts("returns the element on #first") { topic.first }.equals('foo')
  end
end
```

Still sort of the tip of the iceburg, but hopefully that gives you at least a bit of a feeling for it.

I would say apart from the speed thing, what I like the most about riot is how structured it is. It takes away some freedom, but only really the freedom to do bad things. I find the only times I have problems with it are when I am about to write a bad test, and not being able to do it forces me to take a step back and think about what I am doing.

---

Another thing I would mention wrt TDD is [spork](https://github.com/timcharper/spork). The idea is that loading the rails environment can easily take 30-40 seconds, and that can become irritating REALLY fast when you are doing tdd. What spork does is set up a rails environment, then fork the process on every test run. Everything is already in memory, so that makes test runs start really fast.

Currently, they support rspec, cucumber, and test/unit. (sorta planning on contributing riot support one day when I have some time)

Comment: I know there is a insane amount of testing frameworks, and that's why I think it's important to have a centralised reference to compare all of them!

Comment: I love the idea of spork but... 
"Rails 3.0 support is in progress, but is not ready. The master branch is stable and works with rails 2.3.x.
Rspec 2.x support is not ready either."
I can't wait for it to get up to date though as it does save a huge amount of time on even medium sized projects.

Answer (score 2):

I like [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) ([cheatsheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/minitest/1)) because it is quite small and very fast. It includes both unit test and spec systems (as well as mocks and benchmarking). I personally favor unit tests over specs as the syntax of Cucumber and the like seems 'read-only' (the opposite of 'write-only' languages like Perl or APL :).

Comment: As an aside: *reading* minitest is also quite a learning experience.

Comment: @Joerg: Are you serious or sarcastic when you say "quite a learning experience"?

Answer (score 1):

My current favorites are:

[Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) (and [Aruba](https://rubygems.org/gems/pickled_aruba) for CLI)

- The natural language approach is a big plus.
- It's easy to write out
  features in a way that makes sure
  they actually make sense to develop.

[RSpec 2](http://relishapp.com/rspec)

- Again a more natural language approach is a huge help. I hate all that "asserts" mumbo-jumbo.
- Tons of matchers, I haven't run across a condition I couldn't test for like I have with Aruba.
- It's really, really easy to use.

[Autotest](https://rubygems.org/gems/autotest) for continuous testing.

- It can run all the major testing frameworks.
- It has support for growl so I can just see a popup when a test fails.

Comment: Okay, everyone is talking to me about rspec, maybe I should give it a shot.

Comment: Most definitely. The RSpec Book just dropped and it covers the whole gamut from basic BDD concepts to actual implementation of a program from start to finish using Cucumber and RSpec. Plus a whole lot more. Check it: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book